# Finding overlaps between two date intervals grouped by ID

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I have two large data frames, both with the same ID's, and I want to know which date ranges overlap.

**lpr:**

[image]

**tilbud:**

[image]

I want to add a dummy indicating for each row in `lpr` which date ranges are overlapping with the date ranges of `tilbud`.

Rule for overlaps:

```
start_t <= end_l & 
end_t >= stat_l
```

**Desired output:**

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
setDT(lpr)
setkeyv(lpr, c("ID", "start_l", "end_l"))
setDT(tilbud)
setkeyv(tilbud, c("ID", "start_t", "end_t"))

overlap <- foverlaps(lpr, tilbud, 
                     by.x = c("ID", "start_l", "end_l"),
                     by.y = c("ID", "start_t", "end_t"),
                     type = "any"

overlap_df <- as.data.frame(overlap) %>%
        mutate(overlap = case_when(!is.na(start_t) ~ 1,
                                   TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
        select(ID, start_l, end_l, overlap) %>%
        distinct()

lpr_out <- lpr %>%
        left_join(overlap_df)
```

It did work until I merged the dummy for `overlap` back onto my data, as if the `data.table` conversion is doing something to my script. What happens is that my data gets totally messed up, with one ID getting another ID's dates ranges and gender etc.
I've noticed that the problem lies with the `setkeyv`, since removing this from my script removes the problem. But I don't know how to do this without. I'm not used to working with `data.table`, so the solution might be obvious. I've tried `setkeyv(lpr, NULL)` and `setkeyv(tilbud, NULL)` before creating `lpr_out` with no luck.

My real data is a bit different from the one in the `structure` below. My dates are formatted `YYYY/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` (I've used `lubridate::ymd_hms()` followed by `as.Date()` for formatting).

I've also tried:

```
overlap_df <- lpr[tilbud, .(ID,
                            start = x.start_l, end = x.end_l,
                            start2 = i.start_t, end2 = i.end_t),
               on = .(ID,
                     start2 <= end,
                     end2 >= start),
               nomatch = NA]
```

However I get an error saying that I'm specifying non existing columns: `cols[2]='start2'`.
`

**Structure:**

```
lpr <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 
                  6, 6, 7, 7), start_l = structure(c(1551398400, 1551830400, 1560211200, 
                                                     1600214400, 1553126400, 1661472000, 1553990400, 1546646400, 1554854400, 
                                                     1592179200, 1555718400, 1556150400, 1577664000, 1557014400, 1557878400, 
                                                     1622332800, 1559606400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
           end_l = structure(c(1551657600, 1554163200, 1560729600, 1602460800, 
                               1555459200, 1663200000, 1556323200, 1549065600, 1557187200, 
                               1591920000, 1558051200, 1558483200, 1580083200, 1559347200, 
                               1560211200, 1624665600, 1561939200), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                              "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 -17L))

tilbud <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 
                  7, 7), start_t = structure(c(1551052800, 1580515200, 1570579200, 
                                               1646438400, 1639267200, 1661558400, 1546473600, 1639267200, 1554854400, 
                                               1646265600, 1651708800, 1555545600, 1556668800, 1624665600, 1591228800
                  ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), end_t = structure(c(1551744000, 
                                                                                         1580774400, 1577404800, 1657238400, 1639353600, 1662768000, 1553990400, 
                                                                                         1639353600, 1557187200, 1646352000, 1651708800, 1556582400, 1561852800, 
                                                                                         1624752000, 1593561600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't necessarily need `foverlaps` here, though by your logic some of your `overlap` column does not match your bounds constraints.

```r
lpr[tilbud, overlap := 1L, on = .(ID, end_l >= start_t, start_l <= end_t)
  ][, overlap := +(!is.na(overlap))]
#        ID    start_l      end_l overlap
#     <num>     <POSc>     <POSc>   <int>
#  1:     1 2019-03-01 2019-03-04       1
#  2:     1 2019-03-06 2019-04-02       0
#  3:     1 2019-06-11 2019-06-17       0
#  4:     1 2020-09-16 2020-10-12       0
#  5:     2 2019-03-21 2019-04-17       0
#  6:     3 2019-03-31 2019-04-27       1
#  7:     3 2022-08-26 2022-09-15       1
#  8:     4 2019-01-05 2019-02-02       0
#  9:     4 2019-04-10 2019-05-07       1
# 10:     4 2020-06-15 2020-06-12       0
# 11:     5 2019-04-20 2019-05-17       1
# 12:     6 2019-04-25 2019-05-22       1
# 13:     6 2019-05-05 2019-06-01       1
# 14:     6 2019-05-15 2019-06-11       1
# 15:     6 2019-12-30 2020-01-27       0
# 16:     7 2019-06-04 2019-07-01       0
# 17:     7 2021-05-30 2021-06-26       1
```